# IV value read from Binary file, is not proper

Tags: python-2.7, encryption, file-io

I have an encrypted binary file of size 256*N bytes.
The last two bytes of the first page(256 length) contains the IV value to decrypt.
If i fetch that using the below code:

```
infile.seek(240,0)
iv = infile.read(16)
```

(infile is input file). IV value is not matching to that in the bin file.

Also, is it fine if i just send this "iv" to AES.new ? as below code?

```
decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
```

Also, if i have to send a hard coded IV value to AES new function, in what format i need to send it? i have a 16 bytes HEX value and i need to convert it into a byte string right?
Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

### First question

Yes, that seems to be the proper method to read the IV. Make sure you opened the file in binary mode though, not in text mode.

### Second question

Yes, if the IV is a 16 byte binary value that would be correct.

### Third question

Using a constant IV would defeat the purpose of the IV altogether. But if you must use one that is specified as hexadecimals you should [unhexlify](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) it.